# Как правильно прописать  и meta Для коректного отображения в поисковиках

Tags: css3, seo, html, html5, javascript

сверстал одночастичный сайт  переделал под себя. 
Выставил в <title> и meta name те слова которые должны отображаться при поиске сайта в гугле. проиндексировал его. все указановерно.
что я пропустил и как это исправить как найти эти слова где они спрятаны

Answer (score 1):

Google гласит
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291?hl=ru

От себя: иногда требуется время, чтобы поисковик заново прошелся по сайту, и заменил тайтлы  / мета-теги в поисковой выдаче. Если это сайт в одну страницу, ждать придется долго - но можно воспользоваться инструментами для веб-мастера, которые любезно и безвозмездно предоставляет сам Гугл - вот в них можно заново попросить перепарсить страницу / цы.

Answer (score 0):

Да вроде все норм, просто Гугль еще не проиндексировал ваш сайт полностью. Подождите пару дней (может недельку-другую) и все станет на круги свое (ну или попадете в бан, тоже вполне возможный исход :)).

Comment: а почему в бан)?